# Difference between -r and --remove when removing a repository

Tags: linux, package, repository, apt, system-administration

To remove a repository we do it manually by removing the row we have added in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or deleting the file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. But we can also take advantage of add-apt-repository by adding `--remove` so in the example above we would have to write the following to remove the existing repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb games'.
```

But I've seen some people write `-r` instead of `--remove` and I assume they do the same thing?
But I also know that the r flag read all files under each directory, recursively so I wonder what the case would be here. Should you use `-r or --remove`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `add-apt-repository --help`, the help page will tell you that `-r` is just a shortcut for `--remove`.

If you wish to be more explicit, for example, in a script that you plan on sharing, using `--remove` might be a good idea, since it's slightly more readable.

If you're just using the command in your own terminal, `-r` is faster to type.